# Add additional fonts to "My fonts" within Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-fonts

I've noticed that you can now add your own fonts to Google Docs. When clicking the **More fonts...** button, the following dialog box appears:

[image: More fonts Google Docs]

On the right hand side, the **My fonts** section shows some custom fonts that are installed on my Mac. When I select Avenir, the additional weights (Light, Bold, Heavy etc) are not available.

Is it possible to install the full font family without installing an extension? I can't see any additional options to add more.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, look's like Google Drive doesn't allow to add or use fonts that are not included in the [Fonts.Google.com](https://Fonts.Google.com) suite.